# Barry Harris missing ninth tone in the (right) major scale

Tags: scales, chord-theory

In this talk, starting from 55:35, Barry starts talking about his way of playing the major scale which makes the most sense to him (with the added #5)... He says "the major scale is actually 8th degrees and [in fact] should be 9".

I am somewhat familliar with his diminished concept, and his way of playing the major scale makes sense to me, but I can't get over my curiosity to know about the 9 degrees version of this scale, and what can ensue from it, imo I think that it can only be performed in some specefic true temperament tunning mode, because I don't see personally why he wouldn't have played it if it were just within the 12tone ET system.

I haven't heard him mention this anywhere else and I'm curious to know whether anyone knows more about this? any lead would be of great value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what he said and played he is simply including the octave (incorrectly, sorry Barry) in describing them as 8 and 9 degrees at that point in the video. He plays a regular C major scale and says: “It’s 8 degrees and it should be 9.” Then he says: “Here is what the scale is” and he plays his version of the major scale with the added #5. We don’t count the octave as a scale degree so they really are 7 and 8 degrees respectively.

Comment: Your clarification makes perfect sense, thank you.
I guess that my mind just overanalyzed that part and came up with a hyperbolic conclusion.